# Can't access server file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access server files, one for reading and other for writing. The following is the path I am setting to achieve this:

```
var templatePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Templates/SRG_Template.pptx"); 
var outputPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Output/SRG_Document.pptx");
```

However, I am not able to access them.

**Update**: In Template folder lies the PowerPoint template which I am reading to create PowerPoint file in Output folder. When I run the application locally, it works fine but on running on server, the ppt file is not created.

Comment: How are you trying to access them? And what does "not able to access them" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is IIS Security Permission.
Did you try that?

You must grant access to `IIS_IUSRS` user for read, write and modify files on Template and Output folders.
You can read more about this [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313075).